# Не работает js скрипт на мобильных

Tags: javascript

Для валидирования и маски данных кредитной карты использую модуль [creditly.js](https://github.com/wangjohn/creditly)

Он не работает на мобильных с любой платформой. Заметил что и пара других которые я смотрел, чисто js не работают на моб. Возможно это как то просто фикситься ? Есть идеи?)

---

Обновлено:
Как понимаю проблема в том что нажатия клавиатуры мобильного не понимаются. Событие не понимает какая кнопка нажата `key: "Unidentified", code: ""`
В тот момент когда нажатия клавиатуры ПК выглядят так `key: "в", code: "KeyD"`
Есть ли какая то библиотека или способ это пофиксить?

Comment: Ну, мобильный браузер, как не крути, таки отличается от компьютерных. Смотрите, визуально, creditly.js ваш, много думайте.

Comment: то что addEventListener("keypress" а на мобильном нет нажатия кнопки?